# TeamCity logging and muted test story

Tags: java, logging, ant, teamcity

I have a TeamCity Professional 6.5.1 server and several agents where some integration tests for my project are running. The issue is to print out failure events into logs but only for non-muted tests. Previously I have configured ant task to print out message if some test failed

```
    <junit printsummary="on"
           haltonfailure="off"
           failureproperty="some-test-failed"
           errorproperty="some-test-failed"
           timeout="300000">
           ...
    </junit>

    <if>
        <equals arg1="${some-test-failed}" arg2="true" />
        <then>
            <echo level="error" message="Some test failed!" />
        </then>
    </if>
```

but this happens without any awareness of muting and does not give concrete name of test failed.

Is it possible to enable test failure events in TC logging regarding to muted option?

Comment: Why don't just import unit tests reports? Here is what we see in our TC: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/testph.png

Comment: Good idea but it suits for me only if I can locate these reports in some a constant path because actually I need to 'grep' them from some alerting script. As far I know these reports are available in temporary subdirectory under agents 'work' directory. Currently I'm investigating the way how to utilize notification plug-ins for this purpose.